# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209) Unhandled Exception: Object has been disposed

Tags: flutter

I am trying to load image from network into canvas image, but it throws errors here is my code, error says Unhandled Exception: Object has been disposed. I used async for loading image from network and convert into ui.Image

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class FramePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  Future<void> paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    Paint border = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2;
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height), border);
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
        height: size.height * 0.8,
        width: size.width * 0.8,
      ),
      border,
    );
    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
        height: size.height * 0.6,
        width: size.width * 0.6,
      ),
      border,
    );
    ui.Image backgroundImage = await getImage(
        "https://icon-library.com/images/50x50-icon/50x50-icon-0.jpg");
    
    canvas.drawImage(backgroundImage, Offset(0, 0), Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

Future<ui.Image> getImage(String path) async {
  Completer<ImageInfo> completer = Completer();
  var img = new NetworkImage(path);
  img
      .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
      .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
    completer.complete(info);
  }));
  ImageInfo imageInfo = await completer.future;
  return imageInfo.image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that the network image is trying to be loaded on a canvas after it has been drawn. As a workaround, you can synchronously load the image after fetching the image from the URL.

`FutureBuilder` can be used to request for the network image.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getImage(
      'https://icon-library.com/images/50x50-icon/50x50-icon-0.jpg'),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image>
  snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData ? CustomPaint(
      painter: FramePainter(image: snapshot.data!),
    ) : const Text('Loading...');
  }
),
```

Create a constructor on your CustomPainter - this is where the image will be passed to be drawn on the Canvas.

```dart
class FramePainter extends CustomPainter {
  FramePainter({required this.image});
  ui.Image image;

  @override
  Future<void> paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    ...
    // Network Image will be loaded using FutureBuilder
    // ui.Image backgroundImage = await getmage(
    //     "https://icon-library.com/images/50x50-icon/50x50-iIcon-0.jpg");
    canvas.drawImage(image, const Offset(0, 0), Paint());
  }
}
```